# Отправка фото полученной из PSQL в бота телеграм на Aiogram

Tags: python, aiogram

Пишу функцию пагинации с изображениями, необходимо взять из БД значения вида `('photo.png')` и отправить их пользователю, но столкнулся с ошибкой, что нельзя соединить `file_path/ + photo.png`(полученное из бд).
Использовал `str()`, но и это не помогло
Код:

```
@router.callback_query(F.data == "collection_1")
async def input_text_promt(clbck: CallbackQuery, state: FSMContext):
    with psycopg2.connect(*) as con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        page_query = cur.execute("SELECT file_paths FROM files WHERE id = 1")
    if con:
        con.close
    photo = FSInputFile ('photos/' + str(page_query))
    await clbck.message.answer_photo (photo)
```

БД выглядит примерно так:

```
|id     file_paths|
 -----------------
 1       file.png
```

Ошибка:

```
aiogram.exceptions.TelegramNetworkError: Telegram server says ClientOSError:
 [Errno 2] Can not write request body for https://api.telegram.org/bot6231:*/sendPhoto
```

Может есть другой способ реализации данной функции?

P.S. Решение нашёл сам, дело в том что данные из бд брались в виде [(file.png,)]

код Решения

```
with psycopg2.connect(*) as con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    page_query = cur.execute("SELECT file_paths FROM files WHERE id = 2")
    file_paths = cur.fetchall()

    print (file_paths)
    x = file_paths
    y = [item[0] for item in x]

    img = ('image/'.join(y))
    image = FSInputFile ('image/' + img) 
    print (image)
```

await clbck.message.anwer_photo (image)

Comment: Почитайте [это](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/453), может быть поможет